# Which tool to build a simple web front-end to my database

Tags: sql-server

I am a SQL Server DBA and have a database that I would like to access via a web browser. It will be used internally on the intranet and will simply be calling stored procedures in SQL Server to enter data into the database and return data into a simple web page. I am not a developer although I'm pretty good at SQL and scripting with powershell. I may use SSRS later to report on the data.

My question is which is the best tool for a non-developer to rapidly put together a web front end to SQL Server? I was thinking maybe ASP.NET, Ruby, Powershell, PHP, etc. Which is the simplest?

Where should I host the web application? Apache or IIS? I care more about putting something simple together than creating something fancy and flashy. Any suggestions? As you may have gathered I'm after the simplest solution for rapid development, at the cost of something slick and nice looking (there will only be two users, one of them me).

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help. I've got both a Windows 2008 R2 machine and a Debian Linux machine to use as a web server, and have decided to go for ASP.NET on Windows 2008 R2 as that integrates niecly with SQL Server. If I was using MySQL as the back-end I would likely have used PHP. Not sure if the choice of back-end should influence the front-end, but it has in this case. Thanks all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are experienced with SQL Server, I would recommend ASP.NET.

ADO.NET gives you good access to SQL Server, and with SMO, you will also have just about the best access to SQL Server features.  You can access SQL Server from other environments, but nothing is quite as integrated or predictable.

You can call your stored procs with SqlCommand and process the results the SqlDataReader and you'll be in business.

Answer (score 4):

The most rapid option is to hand out MS Access or SQL Sever Management Studio (there's a free [express edition](http://www.microsoft.com/express/database/)) along with a read only account.

PHP is simple and has a well earned reputation for getting stuff done.  PHP is excellent for copying and pasting code, and you can iterate insanely fast in PHP.  PHP can lead to hard-to-maintain applications, and it can be difficult to set up a visual debugger.

Given that you use SQL Server, ASP.NET is also a good option.  This is somewhat harder to setup; you'll need an IIS server, with a configured application.  Iterations are a bit slower.  ASP.NET is easier to maintain and Visual Studio is the best visual debugger around.

Answer (score 3):

How about using the Dynamic data template that comes with Visual Studio. This could be hosted on IIS.

[This walkthrough shows you how to create a basic Web site that uses ASP.NET Dynamic Data. Dynamic Data enables you to create a data-driven Web site with little or no coding.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488469.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

For Data access you can use [OData](http://www.odata.org/). Here is a demo where Scott Hanselman creates an OData front end to StackOverflow database in 30 minutes, with XML and JSON access: [Creating an OData API for StackOverflow including XML and JSON in 30 minutes](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CreatingAnODataAPIForStackOverflowIncludingXMLAndJSONIn30Minutes.aspx).

For administrative access, like phpMyAdmin package, there is no well established one. You may give a try to [IIS Database Manager](http://www.iis.net/download/databasemanager).

Answer (score 0):

I think PHP is a good solution. It's simple to set up, free and there is plenty of documentation on how to create a database management app.
Ruby on Rails is faster to code but a bit more difficult to set up.