# Portable Frontend Data input interface for SQL Server Database

Tags: user-interface, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server Database, I want a front-end graphical user interface for data input, which can be either web or desktop. But it has to be portable I mean it should be used without additional installation of any program. That front-end interface will be used by many users for input data into Database. Can you please help and suggest me?

Answer (score 3):

Please see the link to the similar question. I find it quite helpful.

[Which tool to build a simple web front-end to my database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181881/which-tool-to-build-a-simple-web-front-end-to-my-database)

and this

http://community.spiceworks.com/topic/195850-does-anyone-have-a-quick-and-dirty-way-to-access-ms-sql-data-from-a-web-app

and if you have some free time also this

http://www.academia.edu/4948292/Design_and_Implementation_of_Graphical_User_Interface_for_Relational_Database_Management_System

and potentially this

https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/89751/is-there-a-front-end-application-development-tool.html

I hope it helps (at least a bit!)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone is still looking for this, but https://beekeeperstudio.io is an open source database gui with a portable build.

Windows has a portable exe
Linux has appimage

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest [SQLPage](https://sql.ophir.dev), which will let you build a quick user interface in a few lines of SQL.

It lets you write simple `.sql` files that will be executed against the database, and used to feed data into a [large panel of pre-built components](https://sql.ophir.dev/documentation.sql).

It supports forms, plots, and data creation, visualization, and edition.

[image: sqlpage code example]
[image: sqlpage architecture]